# Azure doesn't use the right certificate

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-functions

I have build a new webapp on Azure. So i followed that steps:

1. Add A Record (A/@/52.173.76.33), a CNAME (CNAME/www/saschamannsde.azurewebsites.net) and a TXT (TXT/@/saschamannsde.azurewebsites.net)
2. Added a custom domain to the webapp (Then it is listed as available host)
3. Upload the PFX and CER and bind it to my domain.

Azure now shows me, that it is a valid Certificate with my hostname saschamanns.de and issued by Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA (ID 134d36755287a5e0718554ff9c9103d13f331d34).

[image: Validation]

If i now typing https://saschamanns.de the browser tells me, i have a false cert, issued for shortener.secureserver.net.

Inside the Supportpage of Azure it tells me two problems:

1. Certificate mismatch detected ( 
   The hostname saschamanns.de is configured to a Certificate with the thumbprint 134d36755287a5e0718554ff9c9103d13f331d34 on this Azure web app. However, the site returned a certificate with thumbprint 22873d8fefeb318394d1b906a5e4657876552d80.) A traceroute gives me: 
   https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5427RCBmMF/ 
   And it looks like it routes to the MS Routes.
2. DNS resolution error detected (As per the current DNS settings, URL saschamanns.de resolves to 184.168.131.241. The web app on Azure however is configured to listen on 52.173.76.33.)
   But i have already set the IP to 52.173.76.33. The other IP comes from my Domain Manager GoDaddy.

Maybe anyone can help to identify the problem?

Comment: Try to turn off your antivirus software if you have an antivirus software scanning? Try to access this web app service from another network environment like Azure VM? Try to restart the web app service?

Comment: I can reproduce this at home, at work. Do you don't run into that error, if you're trying to reach the page?

Comment: yes, the same on my side. try to upload a self-sign cert with a DNS name `saschamanns.de` using [New-SelfSignedCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps). Try to verify if it's a cert misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Dig web interface](https://www.digwebinterface.com/) , **saschamanns.de is also pointing to 184.168.131.241** . What is this 184.168.131.241 ip ?

saschamanns.de.     599 IN  A   184.168.131.241

saschamanns.de.     599 IN  A   52.173.76.33

If you browse the web app , certificate ( Thumbprint : 22873d8fefeb318394d1b906a5e4657876552d80)  showing in browser is issued to **shortener.secureserver.net** .

[image]

Certificate which is binded to web app **is not issued to saschamanns.de**

Can you try bind the certificate again to web app by removing the existing one. Hopefully that should resolve the issue.

Comment: The 184.168.131.241 record was added per default from Godaddy (my domain manager)

Comment: Currently i'm using SNI. Maybe it just works IP based?

Comment: It is not about SNI based. A Record mapping is  not correct. Also binded certificate is also issued to different domain.

Comment: After a long phone call with GoDaddy the strange IP was now removed. Now it works perfectly. :-) Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

I also just ran into the same issue. Basically, the reason why I got the certificate mismatch error was according to the Forwarding Feature of GoDaddy.
If you use the forwarding feature - it will add a locked "A record" entry to the domain pointing to ip.secureserver.net which in my case was 184.168.131.241.
However tanner west explains the forwarding issue in a [gist article](https://gist.github.com/tanner-west/8aa8c9f48518cafab2b87c870696c0aa).

In a nutshell, don´t use the forwarding feature and edit the DNS forwarding manually.

[This is the feature I am talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spt25.png)